# Gem file is requesting dependencies that are installed when upgrading from Rails 4 to Rails 5 but it says it could not find compatible versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, updating

This is my first major upgrade of Rails (v4 to v5).  I've done minor upgrades, like 4.1.1 to 4.2 etc...

I've upgraded to 5.1.1, and I'm getting this dependency error in the console

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionmailer":
  In Gemfile:
    mail_form (= 1.7.0) was resolved to 1.7.0, which depends on
      actionmailer (< 5.2, >= 3.2)

    rails (>= 5.1.1, ~> 5.1) was resolved to 5.1.1, which depends on
      actionmailer (= 5.1.1)
```

however, I have actionmailer 5.1.1 installed.  That looks like what it's asking for.  These seems like an noob question, but it looks like rails MUST have actionmailer 5.1.1 and mail_form can have version less than 5.2 or equal/greater than 3.2.  5.1.1 satisfies both these conditions....so what's going on?

It also says this further down

```
Could not find gem 'rails (>= 5.1.1, ~> 5.1)' in any of the sources.
```

But I've uninstalled and reinstalled rails 5.1.1 to make sure.

**I also tried doing this with 5.0.0 and had the same issue.**

This is just one of many, many "Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem " errors in this bundle.

```
ruby '2.3.1'

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.1', '>= 5.1.1'

gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'yui-compressor'

# gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails',  '= 3.2.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',  '>= 3.3.6'
gem 'draper', '= 3.0.1' 
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.1'
gem "jquery-ui-rails"
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.2'
gem 'redis'
gem 'redis-namespace'
# gem 'turbolinks' 
gem 'jbuilder', '= 2.7.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'devise', '= 4.4.0'
gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.1'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', '~> 0.3.0'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-eventbrite', '~> 0.0.6'
gem 'twitter' #for posting to twitter
gem 'koala' #for posting to facebook
gem 'sprockets-rails', '= 3.2.1'
gem 'sprockets', '~> 3.7', '>= 3.7.1'
gem 'geoip', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.1'
gem 'jsTimezoneDetect-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
# gem 'client_side_validations',  '= 4.2.12' #todo check validations NO RAILS 5
# gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form', '= 3.4.0'
gem 'acts_as_commentable'
gem 'attr_encrypted', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.3'
gem 'httparty', '~> 0.14.0'
gem "skylight"
gem 'braintree'
gem 'bitly', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.1'
# gem 'ahoy_email', '~> 0.2.3'
# gem 'compass-rails' #needed for chosen
# gem 'chosen-rails', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.2'
gem 'bootstrap-table-rails', '~> 1.11'
# gem 'chartjs-ror'
gem 'chartkick', '~> 2.2', '>= 2.2.3'
gem 'groupdate', '= 3.2.0'
gem 'hightop', '~> 0.2.0'
gem 'active_median', '~> 0.1.4'

gem 'bootstrap-tagsinput-rails'
gem 'faker'
gem 'slim'
# gem 'less-rails', '>= 2.8'
# gem 'less-rails', github: 'metaskills/less-rails', branch: 'depends_only_on_less_files'
# gem 'less-rails', git: 'https://github.com/Genkilabs/less-rails' #fix for deprecated Sprockets ImportProcessor
gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'american_date'
gem 'mail_form', '= 1.7.0'
# gem 'cancancan'
gem 'kaminari', '= 1.1.1'
gem 'bootstrap-kaminari-views', '~> 0.0.5'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
gem 'carrierwave-aws'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'carrierwave-base64'
gem 'rmagick', '~> 2.16'
gem 'simple_form_fancy_uploads', '~> 0.2.0'
gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.2.1'
gem 'wysiwyg-rails', '=  2.7.3'
gem 'wicked'
gem 'meta-tags', '= 2.7.0'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 4.0'
gem 'acts_as_list', '~> 0.7.2'
gem 'factory_girl_rails'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'
gem 'paranoia', '~> 2.2', '>= 2.2.1'
gem 'google-analytics-rails', '~> 1.1'
gem 'responders', '= 2.4.0'
gem 'cocoon', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.9'
gem 'momentjs-rails', '>= 2.9.0'
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 4.17.42'
gem 'tzinfo', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.3'
gem 'tzinfo-data'
# gem 'temporal-rails', '~> 0.2.4' #railties dependency
gem 'geocoder', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.1'
gem 'timezone', '~> 1.1'
gem 'browser'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', '~> 3.4'
gem 'hashie', '~> 3.4', '>= 3.4.4'
# Sinatra - might be required for the Sidekiq web UI?
gem 'sinatra', '~> 1.2'

gem 'paypal-sdk-permissions'
gem 'paypal-sdk-rest' #maybe use



# gem 'paypal-sdk-invoice'
# gem 'resque', '~> 1.26'
# gem 'resque-scheduler', '~> 4.1'
# gem 'active_scheduler', '~> 0.0.3'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'gon', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.1'

gem 'puma'
gem 'rack-timeout'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'airbrake', '~> 5.6', '>= 5.6.1'
# gem 'rack-cache', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.1'
gem 'rack-attack', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.1'
gem 'rack-cors', '~> 0.4.0'
gem 'puma_worker_killer', '~> 0.0.7'
gem 'local-subdomain'
gem 'scout_apm'

gem 'concerned_with', '~> 0.1.0'
# gem 'elasticsearch-rails', git: 'git://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails.git'
# gem 'elasticsearch-model', git: 'git://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails.git'

gem 'pusher', '~> 1.3.1'

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  # gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'foreman'
  gem 'guard-rspec', require: false
  # gem 'bullet', '~> 5.0'
  gem 'rake', '~> 11.1', '>= 11.1.1'
  gem 'web-console', '>= 2.3.0'
  # gem 'derailed_benchmarks', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.1'
  # gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 0.10.1'

end


group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails','= 3.7.2'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'mailcatcher', '~> 0.6.4'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.7', '>= 2.7.1'
  gem 'capybara-screenshot', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.13'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem "email_spec"
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'rspec-activejob'
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'lol_dba', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.1'
  gem 'rb-readline'
# gem 'invoice_samples', :git => "https://github.com/paypal/invoice-sdk-ruby.git"

end

group :test do
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'db-query-matchers'
  gem 'timecop'
  gem 'codeclimate-test-reporter'
  gem 'webmock', '~> 2.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'
  gem 'keen'
end
```

Comment: which version of bundler are you using?  Can you post your gemfile please?

Comment: To follow on from @ruby_newbie … have you run `gem update --system` to get the latest gem system? Which version of ruby are you running on (`ruby -v`)? Are you using a ruby manager like RVM? If so, have you updated it recently?

Comment: ruby -v is 2.3.1p112 
bundler is  1.16.1
gem update --system:  yes

Comment: can you try clearing out your lock file and try again

Comment: yes, Gemfile.lock has been deleted this whole process. @Subash

Comment: can you post your `Gemfile` here?

Comment: done @Subash added above

Comment: sometimes, I have to remove the current gemlock file and bundle install afresh

Comment: @NothingToSeeHere what happens if you just go with one version of rails just specify `rails 5.1` or `rails 5.1.1` and try to resolve dependencies for that specific version

Comment: I will try that again  @subash.  Is there a better way to write it than = 5.1.1  --that's how I was writing it before

Comment: @NothingToSeeHere I'm not sure if you even need that `=` if you are specifying just one version, I've never used that

Comment: @Subash  I removed them, but nothing.  

The errors say things like this 

    rails (= 5.1.1) was resolved to 5.1.1, which depends on
      activerecord (= 5.1.1)

so I was "resolving" them in cased that helped.

Comment: What happens when you remove the rails version completely?  After that try running `rvm get stable` and `gem pristine --all`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up rebuilding the gem file line by line starting with just rails and pg and then pasting and bundle installing each new line.

I found I was hanging on "Sinatra".

None of the errors I found in bundling the complete gem file appeared in the line-by-line bundle.  Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

Before you bundle install, are you making sure to have RVM set to the ruby version you need (`rvm use 2.3.1p112`)?

You might also try `bundle update` before `install` and see if that helps.

Comment: No, that's how I get the errors.  By running bundle update